# Hiding and showing content in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with huge sentences as data in the cells. I have given the following example where all data in the tag `<td>` must not be visible until mouse click, but right now each click I do I hide the data and it cannot be brought back.

Please find the bug in my code, such that on the first mouse click it shows all the data and the second mouse it hides it again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname </th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill blah blah blah blah <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50 <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a link for the code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUWHD8EBKK6Y

Comment: Try remove `.hidden{display:none;}` and simply change `$(this).toggleClass("hidden");` to `$(this).toggle();`. `.toggle();` is already a show/hide function. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Hi Martin :)I did that but how do I get it to show again as it goes away completely.

Comment: Your selector is missing the span element. `$("span",this)` will fix it.

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thanks Travis :)

Comment: Consider accepting an answer @RP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, check;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").each(function(i, obj) { 
     $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
     $(this).on("click", function(){
        $("td").toggleClass("hidden");
     });
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname </th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill blah blah blah blah <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50 <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if you want hide only one cell in table, change inner selector like this

```
     $("td").each(function(i, obj) {
         $(this).on("click", function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
         });
      });
```

Better add "hidden" class in html. You can delete this from js

```
$(this).toggleClass("hidden");
```

And add "hidden" class to td elements.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're changing the class on the `td` itself, not the child `span`.

To fix the problem, use `find()` and `toggle()` instead, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.hidden').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname </th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill blah blah blah blah <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50 <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure this is what OP was asking for `"must not be visible until mouse click"`. On the other hand, i think the question is to blame here, not this answer.

Comment: @Joel good point. I think that's an issue with the question given the problem and the HTML provided. Happy to update/delete if the OP can clarify either way

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned per my comment, you can use `.toggle();` instead of using a hide class. `.toggle();` already works as a *show/hide* function. You can then use `.find();` to hide certain elements, instead of hiding the entire element, which is what you encountered after my comment. You have a *span element* with a class. You can simply select the class within your respective td element and do a toggle on that.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("td").click(function(){
                    $(this).find('.hidden').toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .main {
                font-size: 120%;
                color: red;
            }

            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th> 
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jill blah blah blah blah  <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50 <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson <span class="hidden"> hidden information jfkajfksdlf </span></td> 
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```